# Map an array of string to component states in React-Native/ES6

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a component like this:

```
export default class Demo extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
           str1: '',
           str2: '',
           str3: '',
           str4: '',
        }
    }

........
}
```

And the string is like `aaa-bbb-ccc-dd`

How can I split them and add to the component state.
My goal is something like:

```
str1: 'aaa',
str2: 'bbb',
str3: 'ccc',
str4: 'dd'
```

Comment: You might consider using an array instead of slight variations on a property name

Comment: Where is the actual string? Is it `props`?

Comment: CertainPerformance: Thank you for your advice
JackBashford: yes it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new object using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and then use `this.setState()` to finally set the `state` in just one simple movement.

Also notice that it is more performant to set the state just once and use the function provided by react. Setting the state directly like `state[bar] = foo` is a bad practice as the [documentation says](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

```
let string = "aaa-bbb-ccc-dd";

const newState = string.split('-').reduce((a, c, i) => {
    a[`str${i+1}`] = c;
    return a;
}, {})

this.setState(newState)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
let s = "aaa-bbb-ccc-dd";

let state = {}
        
s.split('-').forEach((x,i)=> state[`str${i+1}`]=x )

console.log(state);

// and set state using this.setState(state)
```

Comment: this is bad, he is trying to set the state directly using state[s]=x. which is a bad practice.

Comment: If memory serves, we can't set the component state directly like that.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work:

```
const str = "aaa-bbb-ccc-dd"; 
const arr = srt.split("-");   
this.setState({str1 : arr[0],str2 : arr[1], str3: arr[2], str4 : arr[3]});
```